# Logstash change timestamp to dd-mm-yy only

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

I try to import csv to elasticsearch using Logstash

Field data contains data in dd/mm/yy format - 08/02/23 for example

I need to change timestamp to date-month-year only

Try to use this:

```
date {
          match => ["date", "dd/MM/yy"]
          target => ["@timestamp"]
}
```

But logstash( or elastic) add hour:minute:seconds to my date

Is it possible to change timestamp field only to date-month-year,without time?

Comment: The `date` filter parses a date field according to a given format and stores the timestamp result into the `target` field (e.g. `@timestamp`). A timestamp is by nature a very precise point in time, so that usually includes date AND time. I'm curious why do you want the timestamp to only be date?

Comment: Hello @Val. Because in csv i have only date without time, and we don't care about time, only date is valuable. Elastic add 12:00:00 to every date.

Comment: Ok, but why do you want to store this date in the @timestamp field? @timestamp is only useful if you want to visualize your data in Kibana, you can store your date-only field in order other field, it doesn't have to be `@timestamp`

Comment: @Val, yes i want to visualize data in KIbana, i build a table using this data

Comment: You can still do it with any other date-only field, you don't need to use the @timestamp field

Comment: @Val but elastic automatically add timestamp field? Can you provide an example how i can use date-only field and use it in kibana filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logstash adds a @timestamp field automatically when the event enters event pipeline. But you're completely free to ignore that field altogether and use any other date field in your queries. Just make sure that your `date` is really mapped as a `date` type in your index mapping and you're good to go